# How to stop Caliburn Micro from closing the application when all views are deactivated?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, caliburn.micro

I am in the process of upgrading an old winforms program to WPF that utilizes Caliburn Micro for MVVM and Ninject for DI.

I have updated my solution to a WPF solution which runs a non-generic implementation of the Caliburn Micro bootstrapper.  I do this because I do not currently have a base ShellViewModel to run from.

I'm using a Ninject flavor of bootstrapper instead of the standard Caliburn Micro bootstrapper, since I'm fairly familiar with Ninject.

The bootstrapper looks like this:

```
public class NinjectBootstrapper : Bootstrapper
{
    private const string EXTENSION_PATH = "Plugins";
    public static IKernel Kernel;

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Kernel = new StandardKernel();

        Kernel.Bind<IEventAggregator>()
              .To<EventAggregator>()
              .InSingletonScope();

        Kernel.Bind<ViewModels.IAnalysisOutputTableViewModel>()
              .To<ViewModels.AnalysisOutputTableViewModel>()
              .InSingletonScope();

        Kernel.Bind<IWindowManager>()
            .To<WindowManager>()
            .InSingletonScope();


        Kernel.Bind<FormMain>()
              .ToSelf();
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
    {
        if (serviceType != null)
        {
            return Kernel.Get(serviceType);
        }

        throw new ArgumentNullException("serviceType");
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service)
    {
        return Kernel.GetAll(service);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
    {
        Kernel.Inject(instance);
    }
}
```

To get my main form to startup I was forced to override OnStartup in my App.xaml.cs as such:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        NinjectBootstrapper.Kernel.Get<FormMain>().Show();
    }
}
```

As may be apparent above, I exposed my main Ninject kernel as a public static to get access to it, though I realize this is probably an anti-pattern, and once I have finished converting the program I will resolve this.

I have implemented a new child window of my main form using proper MVVM.  I need to open the window from a button as such:

```
private void dataViewerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    windowManager.ShowWindow(analysisOutputTableViewModel);
}
```

So far so good.

The problem is when I try to close this child window.  Instead of just closing the window, it shuts down my entire program.

I imagine this is because, since this child window is the only window(or view) Caliburn is handling, once it is deactivated Caliburn decides for me that I want to close the program.

Is there any way to stop this automatic close behavior?  Perhaps a different way I should be initializing my main form?

---

#### Update

Using Marwijn's answer below, I was able to get my application closing properly.

In the end I used `Application.Exit();` in my main form's Closing event:

```
private void Form_Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

in conjunction with the following modification to my App.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var mainForm = NinjectBootstrapper.Kernel.Get<FormMain>();
        mainForm.Show();

        mainForm.FormClosed += mainForm_FormClosed;
    }

    void mainForm_FormClosed(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Shutdown(0);
    }
}
```

I can now load WPF windows from my main form using Caliburn Micro and Ninject, and everything shuts down properly and doesn't leave any processes running.  This solution appears like it will work well until I am able to update the main form to WPF.

Comment: Any reason you can't just bootstrap `FormMain` using a generic bootstrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use :

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"
    ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown"
   >
</Application>
```

That way the application will only stop if you explicitly call shutdown.

Comment: While I can't say I really like this approach, but it definitely works in tandem with using `Environment.Exit(0)` inside the `FormClosing` event to close the program.  As an interim solution until the application is fully converted to WPF, this is simple and works well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The reason looks to be that the `WindowManager` in WPF is what's tracking your root VM/window and since your startup code bypasses `WindowManager` and calls `Show` directly on the window, there is no way for CM to know to track it.

Checking CM code and looking at the `Bootstrapper<T>` implementation shows on startup it calls:

```
protected void DisplayRootViewFor(Type viewModelType, IDictionary<string, object> settings = null) 
{
    var windowManager = IoC.Get<IWindowManager>();
    windowManager.ShowWindow(IoC.GetInstance(viewModelType, null), null, settings);
}
```

So it looks like CM already resolves an instance of the root VM and shows it via the window manager.

Is there a reason you can't just make your bootstrapper generic and use `FormMain` as the generic type (or is this just a view? In which case is creating a viewmodel for it that complex??)

```
public class NinjectBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<FormMain>
```

or if not

```
public class NinjectBootstrapper : Bootstrapper<FormMainViewModel>
```

This code:

```
NinjectBootstrapper.Kernel.Get<FormMain>().Show();
```

is equivalent to

```
IoC.GetInstance(viewModelType, ... etc)
```

since `IoC.GetInstance` just calls `GetInstance` on the bootstrapper and your bootstrapped override resolves from the container.

Edit: *Bonus points here since because you removed the dependency on the ninject kernel from the application class you can make it non-static and get rid of that nasty static container resolve*

Alternatively, you could just ensure that `WindowManager` is used to open the window in your current code:

```
var frmMain = NinjectBootstrapper.Kernel.Get<FormMain>();
windowManager.ShowWindow(frmMain);
```

(not sure about dependencies here since `Application` would need to take a dependency on `IWindowManager`)

But still - I would definitely consider not taking the approach you've currently got, and I'm scratching my head as to if there is any issue with using a generic bootstrapper? You don't **need** a shell for it as such, just a root viewmodel which CM will use to resolve the view. (If using MainForm doesn't work, creating a viewmodel to handle it should be trivial... just create MainFormViewModel and that's it! You don't NEED it to be wired up, it can still be codebehind but can be instantiated by CM using a ViewModel-First approach - in which case it should still work)

Edit: I should probably mention that the default conventions won't resolve your `FormMain` view unless you refactor it to `FormMainView`. Either that or change the default conventions

Comment: The problem I'm having with using the generic form of the bootstrapper is that it seems to be looking for WPF(xaml) to load for the view.  Since my main view is winforms, when I use the generic bootstrapper it just loads an empty window with a view not found message inside, and then the main winform loads as a separate window.

Comment: I also tried creating an empty view model to bootstrap, but when it loads it also just opens an empty window with a message that it can't find the associated view.  In this case though it doesn't load the view at all.  Once again I think this means caliburn is looking for WPF to load for the view.